# Use Last Column for a Range(F:LastColumn)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use Last column for my range: `WS.range("F2:LastCol" & LastRow).Cells` my sub works for

`WS.range("F2:K" & LastRow).Cells` but the `Last Column` is dynamic and keeps changing

Thanks

```
Sub QQ()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim rCell As range

Set WS = Sheets("sheet1")

LastRow = WS.range("F" & WS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

LastCol = Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'Also tried: LastCol=rgRange.Cells(rgRange.Count).Column 

For Each rCell In WS.range("F2:LastCol" & LastRow).Cells

STUFF 'The stuff works for WS.range("F2:K" & LastRow).Cells

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LastCol is a number, and the syntax you're using to specify the range requires a letter.

You can find out the column letter for the column number and pass it in to your range definition like this:

```
Sub DynamicRange()
    Dim startCol As String
    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim myCol As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell as Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    startCol = "F"
    startRow = 2
    lastRow = ws.Range(startCol & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = ws.Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    myCol = GetColumnLetter(lastCol)

    Set rng = ws.Range(startCol & startRow & ":" & myCol & lastRow)

    For Each cell In rng
       ' do stuff
    Next cell

    ' check the range we've set
    Debug.Print rng.Address

End Sub

Function GetColumnLetter(colNum As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, colNum).Address(True, False), "$")
    GetColumnLetter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

Comment: Hello Head of Catering, not sure how to apply your code to my Sub. do I add the `innerds` of my sub after `Set rng = ws.Range(startCol & startRow & ":" & myCol & lastRow)` or can I use `rng = ws.Range(startCol & startRow & ":" & myCol & lastRow)` in my sud. Thanks

Comment: You always need the `set` keyword when you're defining a range. I'm not sure I understand your question completely. I edited my answer to include your loop. Does that help?

Comment: Yes that answers my question, I am going to try and use it, I will report back.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Please try to define your loop this way:

```
For Each rCell In WS.range(ws.Range("F2"), Ws.Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Cells
```

or it could go shorter way with this solution (if `WS` is `Activesheet`):

```
For Each rCell In WS.range("F2", Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Cells
```

Comment: Hello KazJaw, I get `Invalid or unqualified reference` and the 1st `.colunm` in `LastCol = Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` is highlighted in blue

Comment: oughta be `ws.columns.count` or use a with statement. btw the first syntax in KazJaw's answer is most reliable-the latter would not work in a worksheet module unless that worksheet happened to be sheet1

Comment: Josie that fix the problem `LastCol = Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    dim wb As Workbook
    dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("sheet name")    
    Set ListObj = ws.ListObjects("table name")

If ListObj Is Nothing Then
        Set ListObj = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$B$15:$Q$16"), , xlYes)
        ListObj.Name = "new table"
Else
        lastRow = ListObj.Range.Columns(1).cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

        ListObj.Resize Range("$B$15:W" & lastRow + 2)
End if
```