# Auto sort to last column

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry about the flury of posting, I am trying to finish a project (there always seems to be one more thing)

I am tring to auto sort to last column starting at F2 I have the following but is not working

Thanks

```
Sub Sort()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("sheet1")

lastRow = ws.Range("F" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastCol = Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Range(ws.Range("F2"), ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Sort _
            Key1:=Range("lastCol"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
            OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
            DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value for Key1 must be a range. You are trying to use the number that is the last column, and that won't work even if you remove the quotation marks.

Replace `Key1:=Range("lastCol")`
with `Key1:=Cells(2, lastCol)`

Note that you can use the [GetColumnLetter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16941495/138938) function I included in my previous answer to get the letter for the lastCol column. If you have the letter, you can use this syntax instead of the Cells version:
`Key1:=Range(myCol & 2)`

To make sure you know what you are sorting, you can add a little bit of debugging code. You can also use the Immediate window and the Watch window to figure this out.

Replace your entire sub with this:

```
Sub Sort()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim sortRng As Range

Set ws = Sheets("sheet1")

lastRow = ws.Range("F" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastCol = Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Range("F2"), ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
Set sortRng = ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)
MsgBox "I will sort this range: " & rng.Address & _
           " using this column: " & sortRng

rng.Sort Key1:=sortRng, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
            OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
            DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Head of Catering, I made the changes, the sub does not error but does not sort either

Comment: I've edited my answer to help you figure out why it isn't sorting the way you expect. Make sure you have the range and the criteria set correctly and it should work.

Comment: I was a little to quick, the message that comes up is `I will sort this range $F$2:$N$5` (which is correct) `using this column: Self(1)` where Self(1) is the last cell in the last column, everything looks corect but no sorting takes place.

Comment: Is the last column the one you want to sort on? What are the values in the column?

Comment: O.K I see, the last Column is sorted, I was unclear in my request `Sorry`, I wanted to sort `All` the colunms in the Range F to LastCol

Comment: So it does that for me. It sorts all of the columns in the range based on the last column. Which column isn't sorting for you?

Comment: All but the last i.e only the last column is sorting