# excel vba sum dynamic last column

Tags: vba, excel

**macro purpose:**

- macro to loop through a folder of csv files
- sum the last 2 columns and place the result in the next 2 adjacent
  cells on row 1

**example:**
file1.csv last 2 columns are K and L so the sum for column L is placed in cell M1 and the sum for column K is placed in cell N1.
file2.csv may have a different amount of columns so have been trying to setup variables for these 4 requirements.

closest example I could find is:
[Use Last Column for a Range(F:LastColumn)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941083/use-last-column-for-a-rangeflastcolumn)

issue I am having is that I have set the last column in file1.csv as a variable but the syntax is not allowed when summing this variable:

```
Range("M1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Columns("lastColLetter:lastColLetter"))
```

not sure how to fix above syntax.
Full code below:

```
    Sub Macro1_Measure1_2()
'
'
Dim my_Filename     As String
Dim lastCol         As Long
Dim lastColLetter   As String
'--------------------------------------------

Workbooks.Open Filename:="file1.csv" '

' variable1: to store last column
' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941083/use-last-column-for-a-rangeflastcolumn
'lastCol = 12 'manual test
lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'option-2
Debug.Print lastCol
lastColLetter = GetColumnLetter(lastCol)

' check the range we've set
Debug.Print lastColLetter

' variable2: to store 2nd last column
' logic = lastCol -1 col

'Range("M1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Columns("L:L")) 'option-1 works but needs to be dynamic
Range("M1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Columns("lastColLetter:lastColLetter")) 'option-2

End Sub

Function GetColumnLetter(colNum As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, colNum).Address(True, False), "$")
    GetColumnLetter = vArr(0)
End Function


'''''''''''
''' END '''
'''''''''''
```

Comment: Try: Range("M1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Columns(lastCol)

Comment: thanks - worked perfectly.

Comment: You are welcome. Of course you spotted the missing closing parenthesys yourself: sorry for the typo

Comment: or just `[M1] = [sum(X:X)]`